# Why deleting a node in linked list fails when explicitly using a variable to save the head of the list?

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm using this function to create a list by pushing a new node to the front.

```
void push(struct Node **head, int newValue)
{    
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        puts("List is empty. The first node will be created now... ");
    }
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = newValue;
    new_node->next = (*head);
    (*head) = new_node;
}
```

I'm populating the list by doing this:

```
  push(&head, 10);
  push(&head, 20);
  push(&head, 30);
  push(&head, 40);
```

This gives me the following list: `40->30->20->10`

Now, I want to delete the element at the head of the list. Here's my delete function:

```
void delete (struct Node **head, int key)
{
    // struct Node *currentNode = (*head);
    
    if ((*head)->data == key)
    {
        struct Node *tmp = (*head);
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
delete(&head, 40);
printList(head);
```

and I get the expected output (i.e. `30->20->10`).

However, if I un-comment the `struct Node *currentNode = (*head);` line and use the `currentNode` pointer instead of `(*head)` like so:

```
void delete (struct Node **head, int key)
{
    struct Node *currentNode = (*head);

    //if the key is at HEAD (the first node)
    if (currentNode->data == key)
    {
        struct Node *tmp = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

, and I call `delete(&head, 40)` and `printList(&head)` again, Iget some values that I believe are garbage (i.e. `0->1`).

My `printList` is this:

```
void printList(struct Node *list)
{
    int index = 0;
    
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        index++;
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

and Node is this:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

What's going on?

***Update***

For this struct,

```
struct Test
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    struct Test *myPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
    myPtr->x = 111;
    printf("Before copyStructOne x is: %d\n", myPtr->x);

    copyStructOne(&myPtr);
    //would expect this print 111 and not 500
    printf("After copyStructOne x is: %d\n", myPtr->x); 
}
void copyStructOne(struct Test **testPtr)
{
 //doesn't this create a local copy like in my original question?
    struct Test *testStr = (*testPtr); 
    testStr->x = 500;
    printf("Inside copyStructOne x is: %d\n", testStr->x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you're using `currentNode`, it contains a copy of what is in `*head`.  However, you only modify the copy, not `*head`, so the head of the list doesn't actually change.  So after the function returns, `head` now points to memory that has been freed, so reading that pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The reason for passing a pointer-to-pointer is to allow a pointer in the calling function to be modified by the called function.

Comment: So, `currentNode` should have been a pointer-to-pointer variable?

Comment: @kingJulian Yes, if you instead had `struct Node **currentNode = head;`, then you could use it the same way you used `head` in the first example.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. It worked. Based on this, I tried to experiment a bit with local copies (see updated answer above) but I think I'm missing something. In my updated example, isn't this the right way to create a local copy? I think this is identical with what I did in my `struct Node *currentNode = (*head);`  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In fact what you have in the modified function is similar to the following

```
int x = 10;
int y = x;
y = 0;
```

After this code snippet the variable x stays unchanged because it is the variable y that initially was initialized by the value of the variable x that was changed.

There is no need to introduce the local variable currentNode within the function.

I suspect that you want to change the function such a way that it would delete any node (not only the first one) that has a value equal to the value of the parameter key.

In this case the function can look the following way

```
int delete (struct Node **head, int key)
{
    while ( *head != NULL && ( *head )->data != key )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    } 

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very nice piece of code you wrote there.